# Visual Studio Team Services Test can't find dll but build succeeds

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project setup as follows:

- Root
- --- Solution A
- --- Solution B
- --- Solution C
- --- Packages

I have VSTS configured to share a common nuget packages folder called Packages in the root. All three solutions create nuget packages as output and Solution C is dependent on the nuget packages from Solution A & B

My VSTS build completes successfully but the unit tests projects can't find the source project references.

The error I get during test is:

```
Failed   TestTracing
Error Message:
Test method Tracing.UnitTests.Tests.TestTracing threw exception:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tracing, Version=1.0.0.19143, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8..' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Stack Trace:
at Tracing.UnitTests.Tests.TestTracing()
```

The tracing.csproj has no nuget package dependencies. Is the issue occuring because I'm both building and consuming the same nuget package in the build process or am I missing something else?

Comment: Is tracing.csproj built during the build process? And in your unit test project\References, did you set "Copy Local" to "true" for tracing project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being with the "Visual Studio Test" step of my VSTS build definition. I had a single step with the following default code:

```
**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**;
```

At output this would generate a single execution of vstest.console.exe:

```
vstest.console.exe ".....\Tracing.dll" ".....\Solution B.dll" "....\Solution C.dll"
```

The issue was that Solution B had a reference to a different version of Tracing.dll and so there was guaranteed to be at least one project incapable of loading the dll.

The (ugly) solution was to break the test step up with one instance for each test dll.

Comment: How do you determine what the DLL conflict is? If I have 100 potentially conflicting DLLs, I need an efficient way to determine this.